# Object creration in Tic tac toe

Tags: oop

I am creating a two player game and I want to be able to restrict users from creating additional player objects.

```
public class Player {
    Symbol symbol;

    public Player() {
        symbol = Symbol.X;
    }
}
```

If I have a public constructor like this, users can keep creating objects and there will be no way to restrict this?

Edit:

Extracting players from an enum

```
public enum Symbol {
    X, O;
}
```

I want to be able to get the symbol from here and assign it to player object when creating it.

Comment: See Singleton or Factory pattern

Comment: Unless you provide some sort of console where players can type in Java code that you blindly execute, they're not going to be able to create objects. Players aren't programmers. They have no access to the data structures used in the game's code.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'm not quite sure what you mean. For all we know the OP could be creating some library that others will use, in which case this could potentially be a valid concern.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I am not sure that is the only criteria you evaluate when you do OO Programming?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```
class Player {

    private static int players = 0;

    private Player(...) {
        ...
    }

    public static Player newPlayer(...) {
        if (players < MAX_PLAYERS) {
            players++;
            return new Player(...);
        }

        throw new TooManyPlayersException(...);
    }

}
```

Comment: Arshajii has considered an interpretation of the Question that makes sense (i.e. that the OP *meant* "programmer" ... and provided a good Answer for that interpretation of the Question.  He **does not deserve** a downvote for *attempting* to understand what the OP is really asking.

Comment: See my comment above. There is a massive [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) here.

Comment: arshaji, @StephenC: I downvote answers when I think the asker is confused and the answer reinforces that confusion. It's just one downvote, though. Not a big deal.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The downvote itself doesn't bother me at all, I'm just slightly disconcerted by the reasoning behind it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down; *"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"*. I don't believe this answer falls in that category. Downvoting a technically correct answer due to a suspicion that it might confuse the OP is misusing downvotes.